Rendering a list after filtering
Disclosure firstly - I am a total newbie to SharePoint.
The problem:
I want to filter and display those chosen items in a list on a view. I know that I can use CAML query and get the wanted items, but what next? I am missing something but totally don't know what it is.
The code works, the question is how can I show it on a view?
My code:
    var oList = website.get_lists().getByTitle('Employees');  

    //Set CAML query 
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();  
    var query = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Team'/><Value Type='Text'>" + currentTeam_name + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(query);  
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    //Load the client context  
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function(){onQuerySucceeded(collListItem)}), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));

    function onQuerySucceeded(collListItem) {
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItempname = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            console.log(oListItempname);      
        }
    }
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
    }

